# ObjectContext ExecuteFunction with async task

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, task

Using Entity Framework 6 with asp.net webapi, and map with stored procedure,
how to convert an `ObjectContext` execution method to an async task ?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the ExecuteFunction you could use the following construct which will provide you with asynchronous execution:

```
Task<SomeResult[]> results = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SomeResult>("EXEC sp_myproc {0}, {1}, {2}", p1, p2, p3).ToArrayAsync();
```

or:

```
SomeResult[] results = await ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SomeResult>("EXEC sp_myproc {0}, {1}, {2}", p1, p2, p3).ToArrayAsync();
```

If you need to use the ExecuteFunction method you could try this:

```
IDbAsyncEnumerable<SomeResult> enumerable = this.ExecuteFunction<SomeResult>("sp_myproc", p1, p2, p3) as IDbAsyncEnumerable<SomeResult>;
IDbAsyncEnumerator<SomeResult> enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();

while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken.None))
{
    SomeResult res = enumerator.Current;
    ...
}
```

This being said, it is worth mentioning that if you decide to use the ExecuteFunction method the actual SQL statement will run on the `ExecuteFunction` line, and not when enumerating the results.

Comment: why not,  await Task.Run(() =>  ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction ... (synchronous code)  ?

Comment: Because that's meaningless code. What's the point of starting a new task and awaiting for it? This will be far less efficient than just calling the method synchronously. Remember that if you want to get any benefit from async programming you should take advantage of I/O completion ports -> which is using the async versions of the functions that the framework provide to you.

Comment: Ok thanks you, i use now SqlQuery to retrieve my dataset store proc, but how can i get the next dataset inside the same store proc with this approch ?

Comment: Hello Darin, any suggestions to call a `ExecuteFunction` version without generic type in async manner?